# Run parallel loops to test Locking on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have implemented a locking mechanism for the function `createConnection` in my code, through which only a single connection can be created at a single instance of time.

I need to test this functionality to test this locking, for which I need to run multiple instances of createConnection in parallel can someone suggest how to implement this?

I am unsure of how to use **async loops**, for this.

```
 function createConnection(user, connectionParams, callback) {
 // Locking implemented here
 // some HTTP requests are being called 
 // Unlocking done here
 }

 for loop (call 50 times to make sure parallel calls are made simultaneously) {
 // call createConnection here multiple times to test locking 
 }
```

How to implement the for loop? What should be the proper implementation of async, asyncEach, await, promise, and return statements?

Comment: Calls are never parallel in node. Only waiting is parallel. At any point in time only one code path is ever executed (unless you are using worker_threads but the model for that is running multiple node.js in parallel - no thread have access to variables in other threads)